# Why is my toon shader not getting pixelated?

Tags: unity, shaders

I made a very simple unlit toon shader that works great, however I have to also pixelate my objects, I tried adding this part marked in blue that modifies the UVs but that did not have the desired effect, how can I change this up so my toon shader also gets pixelated?

[image]

Comment: Note that no output from the pixelation effect feeds as input into the lighting calculation that decides where the line between bright and shaded should go. Shader graphs don't work by spooky action at a distance: if you want something to affect the output, it must be wired into it as input.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your pixelation is working properly, so maybe it's the toon shading which is making it look too smooth. Try moving the pixelation to the end of the process after everything else is combined?

Comment: This answer would be more helpful if it illustrated *how* to move the pixelation later in the process.